# Is there a standard file format for Magic the Gathering games?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, notation

I like to play games of Magic solitaire to test my decks (particularly Commander games, but the same would apply to any game). I also like to share the raw data from the game with my friends. Currently, I simply record the state of the game, transcribe it, and send it - but that requires them to keep a constant mental image of the entire game, including hand contents.

Naturally, using a computer program for this would reduce the mental burden. But if I'm going to do that, I really need to have a file format I can send the game files in. So my question is... is there a standardized file format for describing the events of a Magic game? Something like what PGN does for Chess, but for Magic.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need a standard file format, you need a program that can record and playback from **some** format.

Answer (score 2):

- Right now, the closest thing to an "industry standard" for sharing games is video, using services such as Twitch TV and YouTube. This is how Wizards does event coverage and how many Magic writers share their games.

  Players often record their voice as they play or go back later and add commentary. [Here is a fairly typical example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGXG5rNe_tI).
- Magic Online keeps a history of game states that could be used for replays, but access to the data has generally been limited ([leading to players resorting to engine quirks and workarounds to get at it](http://www.starcitygames.com/php/news/print.php?Article=10346)). Last I checked, the data's still not easily accessible, nor is it very portable or shareable.